# How do Bootstrap 4 board cards?

Tags: bootstrap-4

I am using bootstrap 4 beta.
I need to create a board cards or the board Trello or Github. I appreciate the ideas that can help me.

I thought so within a .row but the interior columns are 12 and narrow.
I leave some images to the idea:

[image]

Comment: you should be need to make some code which you try by your self.

Answer (score 0):

There is not a component to make that. But you can do it with the grid.

For example if you want 3 sections like as: "To Do", "In progress" and "Done"

```html
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row justify-content-around">
        <div class="col-3">YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>
        <div class="col-3">YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>
        <div class="col-3">YOUR CONTENT HERE</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Replace "Your content here" for Bootstrap 4 cards items